# Change the value of a javascript using browsercontrol using vb.net

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, vb.net

First of all im sorry if this question has been posted before.

My problem is this, I have made a simple browser and want to change the value of the attribute. I know the the name i want to change and i have used this to try to change it when i click the button. CashKingCash is the attribute and i only get an error when i click the button. There are no compiling errors.

Anyone know why

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
  WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("CashKingCash").SetAttribute("value", goldtextbox.Text)
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to call the `CashKingCash` function with arguments, you can simply alter your syntax (pulled from the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
Private Sub InvokeTestMethod()
    If (Not (WebBrowser1.Document Is Nothing)) Then 
        Dim ObjArr(2) As Object
        ObjArr(0) = CObj(New String("value"))
        ObjArr(1) = CObj(New String(goldtextbox.Text))
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("CashKingCash", ObjArr)
    End If 
End Sub
```

`SetAttribute` is to alter attributes of an [HtmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement(v=vs.110).aspx) class; if that's what you want do to, you'd need to use something like `GetElementById` to get a reference to the element, and then use `SetAttribute`.